# Why cannot the operation of logarithms and exponents obtain accurate solutions?

Tags: equation-solving

```
In[22]:= 5^Log[10, 30] (1/3)^Log[10, 1/2]

Out[22]= 3^(Log[2]/Log[10]) 5^(Log[30]/Log[10])
```

The correct result should be:

```
5^Log[10, 30] (1/3)^Log[10, 1/2]==15
```

Comment: Why do you assume that Mma is **inaccurate** without doing a simple check, e.g., `5^Log[10, 30] (1/3)^Log[10, 1/2] // N[#, 100] &`. This would have convinced you that it is just an alternate representation needing simplification to put it in the desired form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r=5^Log[10,30] *(1/3)^Log[10,1/2]
ExpToTrig[r]//FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
3^(Log[2]/Log[10]) 5^(Log[30]/Log[10]) // Log // FullSimplify
%// Exp
```

> `15`